# Make two sine waves equal perpendicular distance apart

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, plane-curves

I'm trying to create two sine waves **A** and **B** such that all **A[x]** is equidistant to **B[x]**.

Adding a constant to the second equation does not work:

`graph sin(x) and sin(x)+0.5`

> [image]

The distance between the diagonal lines seem similar, but the crest and troughs are different.

---

Adding another wave function seems to get closer, but still not exact:

`graph y=sin(x) and y=sin(x)+0.2cos^2(x)+0.5`

> [image]

---

Okay so it seems like there's no such wave that can fit the my description, so I'm wondering how I would calculate **B[x]** given **A[x]**.

In my comment below I know how to create the second wave, but I'm unsure how to obtain a point on B given x.

Comment: Why do you think the second function is a sine wave too?  (It isn't.)

Comment: I believe one way to go about it is to plot a curve, using your original curve, that is always a certain distance away from your original curve.  One way to do this is to parametrize your curve, which you can then treat as a function of time.  At each point on the curve, you then plot a point for the new curve that is at the proper distance.  You will also need to know the slope of the original sine function, in order to know which side of the sine function to measure the distance.  The main problem is that the second curve will not be a sine function.

Comment: I think I understand. For every point on the original curve, take two points to calculate the slope; the slope perpendicular will be `p_slope = -1/slope`. The angle would be `atan(p_slope)`. Then, a point on the new curve must be `(x+cos(angle)*dist, y+sin(angle)*dist)`.

Comment: Here it is: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pjp79kry06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeking are [parallel curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve) to $y=\sin x$.

In general, for a curve given parametrically by $x=f(t), y=g(t)$, 
one parallel curve a distance $a$ from it is given by
$$
x= f(t)+\frac{ag'(t)}{\sqrt {{f'(t)}^2+{g'(t)}^2}} \\
y=g(t)-\frac{af'(t)}{\sqrt {{f'(t)}^2+{g'(t)}^2}}.
$$
The other parallel curve at this distance is given by taking $-a$.

For the sine curve $x=t, y=\sin t$, these give 
$$
x(t)=t+\frac{a \cos t}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}},\,y(t)=\sin t + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}}.
$$
For small $a$, you get a curve similar to a sine curve.  Here is $y=\sin x$ with its parallel curves for $a=\frac{1}{2}$. [image: y=sin x with its two parallel curves at a distance of 1/2]

For larger $a$, the curve gets weirder, like this, with $a=2$:
[image]